How can I fix a content type error with cfimp / Contentful Import?
I want to use cfimp to import my CSV to Contentful. My CSV has 2 columns that match IDs to those in Contentful. Everything works when the fields are set to the basic ShortText content type, but not if one of the fields is set to RichText.
I am getting this error:
20:07:46 - InvalidEntry: Status: 422 - Unprocessable Entity - Message: Validation error - Details: The type of "value" is incorrect, expected type: RichText - Request ID: asdfas
CSV format:
ColA,ColB
ValueA,ValueB
I tried different content type settings in Contentful and tried to find where I could set the data type in cfimp. I also looked for places where I may be getting blocked by Contentful due to the tier I'm on or other permissions.
